# Android Studio complains that a used variable is never used

Tags: android, android-studio

My problem is something like this:
I am working with Calendar dates, and have a few variables.
I declare them at the top like such:

```
int year, firstMonth, lastMonth, ...;
```

I assign them values in a function based on a DatePicker as such:

```
private void setDateTimes(){
...
year = newDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
firstMonth = newDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
...
}
```

and I use them both in an on-click as such:

```
Calendar begin = Calendar.getInstance();
begin.set(year, firstMonth,...);
```

Now, firstMonth is behaving fine. Its value is passed, Android Studio doesn't complain. But year is another story. Despite me clearly declaring, assigning, and using it in the same areas as firstMonth, it's greyed out in the setDateTimes function with a warning claiming the variable is never used. When I print out begin via toString, I see that Month is set fine, to proper values, but year is defaulted to 0.

Comment: You probably have another local variable `year`.

Comment: That did it.  I'd stupidly used the term "year" on the OnDateChangeListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cleaning up my questions and posting that yes, as discussed in a comment, it was that another variable of the same name was used.